# не отправляется текст на почту

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, gmail

Привет. У меня возникла проблема, что на тестовом приложении не отправляются данные на почту :

## Development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
config.cache_classes = false

# Do not eager load code on boot.
config.eager_load = false

# Show full error reports and disable caching.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send.
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port:   3000 }

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp


config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => ENV['gmail_username'],
 :password             => ENV['gmail_password'],
 :authentication       => "plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

## sample_email.text.erb

```
 <%= @contact.nickname %>   
 <%= @contact.mail %> 
 <%= @contact.theme %> 
 <%= @contact.text %>
```

## contacts_mailer.rb

```
class ContactsMailer < ApplicationMailer

    default from: "info@mystorelocalhost.com"
            #template_path: 'contacts_mailer/sample_email'

    def sample_email(contact) # название вьюхи маилера и аргумент 
        @contact = contact
    mail(to: 'lmyhope3@gmail.com' , subject: 'Sample Email')
  end

end
```

## contacts.controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    @contacts = Contact.all
    end

    def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end


  def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
        redirect_to contacts_path
        ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
    end
  end


  private
  def contact_params 
    params.require(:contact).permit(:nickname, :mail, :theme, :text)
  end

end
```

## console

```
 Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-03 14:40:32 +0300
 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT    `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
   Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"kAK/xsE34tm5NyJSitzG2eB/ky38R/9cKq1ooYUgp7JviBlk52S     r+uxA3RkI5HS+OKwFGpuC0k2Dmj4VqPTrJg==", "contact"=>   {"nickname"=>"testnickname123", "mail"=>"testma123@mail.com",    "theme"=>"testtheme123", "text"=>"testtext123"}, "commit"=>"Create    Contact"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `contacts` (`nickname`, `mail`,  `theme`,  `text`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('testnickname123',   'testma123@mail.com', 'testtheme123', 'testtext123', '2016-06-03    11:40:32', '2016-06-03 11:40:32')
   (66.7ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/contacts
    Rendered contacts_mailer/sample_email.text.erb within   layouts/mailer  (2.1ms)

ContactsMailer#sample_email: processed outbound mail in 203.8ms

Sent mail to lmyhope3@gmail.com (545.6ms)
Date: Fri, 03 Jun 2016 14:40:32 +0300
From: info@mystorelocalhost.com
To: lmyhope3@gmail.com
Message-ID: <57516cb0a62c9_2f205f21f483369a@g6hp.mail>
Subject: Sample Email
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

 testnickname123   
 testma123@mail.com 
 testtheme123 
 testtext123 

Completed 302 Found in 905ms (ActiveRecord: 69.1ms)
```

Comment: `From: info@mystorelocalhost.com` <- не уверен, что Gmail это одобрит. Разве что у вас используется привязанная к этому домену почта. В `ENV` у вас точно лежит что надо? Отладчиком смотрели?

Comment: Я вроде с горем пополам настроил, Да, Вы были правы и в этом тоже я ошибся. Но вот теперь приходят уведомления на почту, только они улетают в папку "спам". Что делать не знаете? :)

Comment: Проехаться по чеклисту массовых рассылок ([вот гугловый](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)), поискать по нему косяки в своих письмах.